# Google Earth Engine data acquisition with a multipolygon shapefile uploaded as table asset

Tags: javascript, geojson, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I uploaded a shapefile with some polygons of my area of study as a asset table in Google Earth Engine. 
Now I am trying to export the displayed data (several Sentinel-2 bands) as GeoTIFF to my Drive using the previous table as geometry.

The code as follows:

```
// Export image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: scene,
  description: 'Areas of study',
  scale: 30,
  region: table  // this is the imported multi polygon asset 
});
```

It is not working and received a notification:

[image: notification]

How can I use that asset as boundary to export the data?
Otherwise,
which is the best way to export the data? Using only one polygon? Creating it within the GEE geometry tools?

Comment: Search in this site. There are several Q&A of this topic

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code using a single polygon as geometry. There is no option to use a multipolygon to download and clip raster, but it is possible to use it to download reduced data in table format. 
I am starting to organize it in geodatabases to work with ArcMap model builder and clip it.